# can't have new line in python with two variable using \n

Tags: python, python-3.x

why i can't have a new line with two variables while i can with a variable and string?
I try using the \n but it does not works
Thank you.

```
a = 10
b = 2

print(int(a//b)+\n+ float(a//b))
```

need output to be;

```
5
5.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally go with [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75829211/364696) (it's the most flexible, and it reads nicely; among other things, it makes it trivial to enforce the two digit precision you're expecting, where plain `str()` conversions will never turn `float(5)` into `5.00`), but for simple cases like "Must print a few distinct values on separate lines", you can just change the default separator from a single space to a newline, and print the values as separate arguments:

```
print(a//b, float(a//b), sep='\n')
```

which outputs:

```
5
5.0
```

Note that I'm not trying to concatenate strings here (no `+` in sight), just specifying the two things to print as separate positional arguments, and telling `print` what to put between them.

Side-note: I removed the `int()` call, because when the inputs are both `int`, and you use `//`, the floor division operator, the result is already an `int`, so calling it is redundant. I also strongly suspect `floor(a//b)` is not what you want (since it converts to `float` *after* floor division; if the result wasn't already evenly divisible, you'd lose information to the floor division, and the "cast" to `float` couldn't recover it). Most likely, what you really want is:

```
print(a//b, a/b, sep='\n')
```

using `/` in the second case for "true division" (where, when the inputs are `int`s or `float`s, the result is a `float` with the result, including as much precision as `float` can handle for the result of dividing the two operands). The output doesn't change for your specific example inputs, but if the inputs were, say, `a = 15` and `b = 12`, you'd get an output of:

```
1
1.25
```

where using your current `float(a//b)` would produce:

```
1
1.0
```

Comment: Good point about `int` not being required...

Answer (score 2):

I would use an [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) to make your life easier:

```
a = 10
b = 2
print(f'{int(a//b)}\n{float(a//b)}')
```

Output:

```
5
5.0
```

Note if you want more decimal places in the float value you can use a [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
print(f'{int(a//b)}\n{float(a//b):.2f}')
```

Output:

```
5
5.00
```

Note (as pointed out by @ShadowRanger in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75829241/9473764)), `//` returns an integer when using integer inputs so there is no need to convert it to one using `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this to mix different object-types:

```
print(str(int(a//b))+'\n'+ str(float(a//b)))
```